# ASP.NET Core + Docker -> Make available on local network

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

How can I run a docker image and make it available (at least) on the local network?

I'm making a .net core api server, and I am running

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample microsoft/dotnet-samples:aspnetapp
```

which works for localhost:8000. But now I need to access it from devices on the same network (next step would be online, but that comes later [bane voice])

I have next to zero networking experience, so I apologize if my goal is something absurd that can not be done

Any help greatly appreciated, even just links to relevant articles.

Further information: I'm creating a web page using Vue.js. This web page fetches it's data from controllers in a  .net core api, storing data in ms sql server.
The api is fully functional, locally (running through visual studio, using IIS?) , and I am trying to learn how to make it available on the local network for testing and demoing.
Using docker is not a strict requirement, but it seems like a comfy solution

Answer (score 0):

you can just access it by `{your-private-ip}:8000` from any other device in same network. But make sure that any of your firewall is not blocking the 8000 ports inside the network.